# how to give directions for a Pong game from outside the game loop?

Tags: python, pygame, python-multithreading, asyncsocket, python-sockets

I am trying to use a simple Server/Client socket to control the paddle in the game. The idea is to make the client able to control the paddle by sending directions to a server which will pass this directions to the game. so i have created to threads one to be listening for client's directions and storing them in a varibale, and the other thread is for running the game.
The problem is that when the client send the lettre "z" (to move the paddle up) the game starts but he send another lettre the game crushes.

I don't know if i have explained enough the problem, I'm new in python and i'll appriciate your help to tell me how to fix the problem !

Here is my code :

```
import socket
import threading
from threading import RLock
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Pong(object):
    def __init__(self, screensize):

        self.screensize = screensize

        self.centerx = int(screensize[0]*0.5)
        self.centery = int(screensize[1]*0.5)

        self.radius = 8

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.centerx-self.radius,
                            self.centery-self.radius,
                            self.radius*2, self.radius*2)

        self.color = (100,100,255)

        self.direction = [1,1]

        self.speedx = 2
        self.speedy = 5


        self.hit_edge_left = False
        self.hit_edge_right = False

    def update(self, player_paddle, ai_paddle):

        self.centerx += self.direction[0]*self.speedx
        self.centery += self.direction[1]*self.speedy

        self.rect.center = (self.centerx, self.centery)

        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.direction[1] = 1
        elif self.rect.bottom >= self.screensize[1]-1:
            self.direction[1] = -1

        if self.rect.right >= self.screensize[0]-1:
            self.hit_edge_right = True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.hit_edge_left = True



        if self.rect.colliderect(player_paddle.rect):
            self.direction[0] = -1
        if self.rect.colliderect(ai_paddle.rect):
            self.direction[0] = 1

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.rect.center, self.radius, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect.center, self.radius, 1)


class AIPaddle(object):
    def __init__(self, screensize):
        self.screensize = screensize

        self.centerx = 5
        self.centery = int(screensize[1]*0.5)

        self.height = 100
        self.width = 10

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, self.centery-int(self.height*0.5), self.width, self.height)

        self.color = (255,100,100)


        self.speed = 3

    def update(self, pong):
        if pong.rect.top < self.rect.top:
            self.centery -= self.speed
        elif pong.rect.bottom > self.rect.bottom:
            self.centery += self.speed

        self.rect.center = (self.centerx, self.centery)

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 1)


class PlayerPaddle(object):
    def __init__(self, screensize):
        self.screensize = screensize

        self.centerx = screensize[0]-5
        self.centery = int(screensize[1]*0.5)

        self.height = 100
        self.width = 10

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, self.centery-int(self.height*0.5), self.width, self.height)

        self.color = (100,255,100)

        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = 0

    def update(self):
        self.centery += self.direction*self.speed

        self.rect.center = (self.centerx, self.centery)
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > self.screensize[1]-1:
            self.rect.bottom = self.screensize[1]-1

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 1)

class _Directions(object):
    data = ""

    def __init__(self):
        _Directions.data = ""

    def set_Data(self, data_Val):
        _Directions.data = data_Val

    def get_Data(self):
        return _Directions.data




def pongGame(Direct_Data):
    pygame.init()

    screensize = (640,480)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


    pong = Pong(screensize)
    ai_paddle = AIPaddle(screensize)
    player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screensize)

    running = True

    while running:
        #fps limiting/reporting phase
        clock.tick(64)

        #event handling phase
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

        if(Direct_Data.get_Data() == "z"):
            player_paddle.direction = -1
        elif(Direct_Data.get_Data() == "s"):
            player_paddle.direction = 1

        #object updating phase
        ai_paddle.update(pong)
        player_paddle.update()
        pong.update(player_paddle, ai_paddle)


        if pong.hit_edge_left:
            print ("You Won")
            pong = Pong(screensize)
            ai_paddle = AIPaddle(screensize)
            player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screensize)

        elif pong.hit_edge_right:
            print ("You Lose")
            pong = Pong(screensize)
            ai_paddle = AIPaddle(screensize)
            player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screensize)


        #rendering phase
        screen.fill((100,100,100))

        ai_paddle.render(screen)
        player_paddle.render(screen)
        pong.render(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()


def get_Directions(Direct_Data, client):
    data = client.recv(1024).decode()
    Direct_Data.set_Data(data)
    client.send(data.encode())


def gameStart():

    verrou = RLock()
    Direct_Data = _Directions()
    server = socket.socket()
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 1234

    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(1)
    print ("[*] Server started !")
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print("[*] Got connection from ip: ", addr[0])
    while True:

        with verrou:

            t = threading.Thread(target=get_Directions, args=[Direct_Data, client])

            t1 = threading.Thread(target=pongGame, args=[Direct_Data])
        t.start()
        t1.start()

    client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameStart()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for 1024 bytes of data, and it doesn't arrive, so the thread hangs. Either change that to 1, if you are sending key-by-key, or use non-blocking sockets.

You also don't use new socket to connect to the listening one. You need two of them. One is server, one is client.

Here is what you want, a little bit simplified. It only changes the window background. You should stick with threading module if you are seriously planning a networking game. It gives you more flexibility than low-level threads. But this code is good enough to see how to do what you want. Also, there is no timestamping and synchronization. When using this on localhost and local ethernet it'll work fine.

Code:

```
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from time import sleep
from collections import deque
import pygame
import socket

running = 1
done = 0
evt_queue = deque() # deque() is thread safe with fast memory access of end items

def Quit ():
    global running
    print "Quitting"
    running = 0
    while done!=2:
        sleep(0.001)

def sender ():
    """Runs in thread and sends all valid events through socket."""
    global done
    print "Starting sender..."
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
    print "Sender connected!"
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                s.send("Q")
                break
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode:
                    # Ensure only one byte is always sent:
                    k = event.unicode.encode("UTF-8")[0].upper()
                    s.send(k)
                    if k=="Q": break
    s.close()
    done += 1
    print "Sender done!"

def listener (client):
    """Thread that waits for events from client and puts them on queue."""
    global done
    print "Listening!"
    while running:
        try: e = client.recv(1) # Breaks when sender closes the connection
        except: break
        evt_queue.append(e)
    done += 1
    print "Listener done!"

# Dictionary with events and their associated functions
actions = {
    "W":
        lambda: screen.fill((255, 255, 255)),
    "K":
        lambda: screen.fill((0, 0, 0)),
    "R":
        lambda: screen.fill((255, 0, 0)),
    "G":
        lambda: screen.fill((0, 255, 0)),
    "B":
        lambda: screen.fill((0, 0, 255)),
    "Q": Quit,
    None: lambda: None}

def MainLoop ():
    """Manages the game. This example only changes window colours."""
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while running:
        try: e = evt_queue.popleft()
        except: e = None
        action = actions.get(e, actions[None])
        action()
        clock.tick(64)
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
s.listen(1)
thread(sender,())
print "Waiting for connection..."
client, address = s.accept()
print "Connection from", address
thread(listener,(client,))
MainLoop()
s.close()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: i tried to use a non-blocking socket but i couldn't fix it. i'am asking about how to notify the game about the new incoming commands while it is looping to draw the components ?

Comment: Use a queue. Receive commands as I said, enque them along with their timestamp, then process them at the first opportunity. For that I advise you to implement timers-like system. I.e. each FPS you check if something is on the queue and if enough time has passed you activate it. Ignore any too fast changes, and that's all. Works like a charm.

Comment: that seems a good idea to solve the problem but i'm affraid to not be able to implement it the right way, as i said i'm new in python i'll be thankful if you give me some code to start with !

Comment: BTW, don't put main loop inside a thread, your game will close if not for some blocking procedure at the end, or unless run from console or IDLE. Your threads should be event handeling function that sends them through socket and event listener that fills the queue. Main loop runs in a main thread and is responsible for drawing and processing the queue.

Comment: I'll write you simplistic example tomorrow.

Comment: thanks @Dalen i appreciate your help i'll wait for your example

Comment: thanks for your time @Dalen i tried the code above (i changed some lines because i am using python 3) but it crushes !! by the way i have resolved the problem based on your suggestions by using a queue and threading

Comment: It works on Py27 with no problems. And it shouldn't be hard to translate to 3, few changes only. And it's just an example anyway. I'm glad my suggestion helped you.

Comment: yes it helped me a lot and i am wondering if i can ask you some questions tomorrow or in the near future when i face a problem in this mini-project!

Comment: Feel free! No problems. Although if it is a bigger issue do post a new question and notify me about it. We should not clutter this one with too many digressions. Oh, and, +1 for cute code. You have a style. Perhaps overcomplicating a bit, but nice expression.